# Oscommerce Product Name and attribute to PayPal account

Tags: php, paypal, oscommerce

I am trying to send Product name and Its attributes(like size,color etc) to the pay-pal account so that merchant is able to view order details like cost, quantity,Product name,attribute etc on his PayPal account itself they don't have to migrate to admin panel of oscommerce to check the order details.I am searching for any supporting module for this purpose and getting "osCommerce PayPal IPN Module v1.0 For 2.2MS2" in search result but I don't think it is helpful for me.Apart from that I am trying to change the coding of Pay-pal module file(like pay-pal.php or pay-pal.php etc) so that I can send product name and its attribute to the PayPal account but nothing works for me.Can anyone suggest me something relevant solution for this as I am novice to Os-commerce and web-designing.

Thanks 
Sunil Rai

Answer (score 0):

You can use the paypal itemized to send description,size,color for each item while sending to paypal. Please have a look at this contribution  [Paypal Itemized](http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,6783)